# Message lost and duplicates in GCP Pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

I'm running into a issue reading GCP PubSub from Dataflow where when publish large number of messages in short period of time, Dataflow will receive most of the sent messages, except some messages will be lost, and some other messages would be duplicated. And the most weird part is that the number of lost messages will be exactly the same as the number of messages being duplicated.

In one of the examples, I send 4,000 messages in 5 sec, and in total 4,000 messages were received, but 9 messages were lost, and exactly 9 messages were duplicated.

The way I determine the duplicates is via logging. I'm logging every message that is published to Pubsub along with the message id generated by pubsub. I'm also logging the message right after reading from PubsubIO in a Pardo transformation.

The way I read from Pubsub in Dataflow is using `org.apache.beam.sdk.ioPubsubIO`:

```java
public interface Options extends GcpOptions, DataflowPipelineOptions {

    // PUBSUB URL
    @Description("Pubsub URL")
    @Default.String("https://pubsub.googleapis.com")
    String getPubsubRootUrl();
    void setPubsubRootUrl(String value);

    // TOPIC
    @Description("Topic")
    @Default.String("projects/test-project/topics/test_topic")
    String getTopic();
    void setTopic(String value);

...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);


    options.setStreaming(true);
    options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);

    ...

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    pipeline.apply(PubsubIO
                 .<String>read()
                 .topic(options.getTopic())
                 .withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
            )

            .apply("Logging data coming out of Pubsub", ParDo
                .of(some_logging_transformation)
            )

            .apply("Saving data into db", ParDo
                .of(some_output_transformation)
            )
            ;


    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();


}
```

I wonder if this is a known issue in Pubsub or PubsubIO?

**UPDATE:**
tried 4000 request with pubsub emulator, no missing data and no duplicates

**UPDATE #2:**

I went through some more experiments and found that the duplicating messages are taking the `message_id` from the missing ones. Because the direction of the issue has been diverted from it's origin quite a bit, I decide to post another question with detailed logs as well as the code I used to publish and receive messages.
link to the new question: [Google Cloud Pubsub Data lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250348/google-cloud-pubsub-data-lost)

Comment: Could you share the job ID of the pipeline?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made a simple pipeline which reads pubsub using pubsbuIO, parse into object, save to a Neo4j database. On a quick run of sending 3000 request, 13 were missing and 13 were duplicated. The job id is 2017-05-24_08_46_18-1297374047328352490

Comment: How are you determining duplicated vs. lost messages?

Comment: In my setup, each message been sent to pubsub is essentially a fake user session with incrementing session id. After reading from PubsubIO, I logged all messages that has been received during the first transformation following pubsubIO, and then dumped the message into a database. From there, by comparing the session id of each message been received, I can list out all the session id that is associated with more than one message. And since the session id increments by 1 each time, I can track which id is missing

Comment: So you are determining duplicates via logging? ParDos can be reexecuted, so that does not necessarily mean there were duplicates.

Comment: Yes, logging is one of the ways I used to determine both duplicates and missing data. I'm not that worried about the duplicates, since pubsub does not guarantees delivery only once per message, and I can put an index in the database to ignore the duplicates. It is missing message and the fact that total number of messages equals the number of messages sent that worries me.

Comment: I went through some more experiments and found that the duplicating messages are taking the message_id from the missing ones. Because the direction of the issue has been diverted from it's origin quite a bit, I decide to post another question with detailed logs as well as the code I used to publish and receive messages. link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250348/google-cloud-pubsub-data-lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I talked with a Google guy from the PubSub team. It seems to be caused by a thread-safety issue with the Python client. Please refer to the accepted answer for [Google Cloud Pubsub Data lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250348/google-cloud-pubsub-data-lost) for the response from Google

Comment: The issue seems to be solve in version 0.29 of the python client