# Google Cloud Pubsub Data lost

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm experiencing a problem with GCP pubsub where a small percentage of data was lost when publishing thousands of messages in couple seconds.

I'm logging both `message_id` from pubsub and a `session_id` unique to each message on both the publishing end as well as the receiving end, and the result I'm seeing is that some message on the receiving end has same `session_id`, but different `message_id`. Also, some messages were missing.

For example, in one test I send 5,000 messages to pubsub, and exactly 5,000 messages were received, with 8 messages lost. The log lost messages look like this:

```
MISSING sessionId:sessionId: 731 (missing in log from pull request, but present in log from Flask API)

messageId FOUND: messageId:108562396466545

API: 200 **** sessionId: 731, messageId:108562396466545 ******(Log from Flask API)

Pubsub: sessionId: 730, messageId:108562396466545(Log from pull request)
```

And the duplicates looks like:

```
======= Duplicates FOUND on sessionId: 730=======

sessionId: 730, messageId:108562396466545

sessionId: 730, messageId:108561339282318

(both are logs from pull request)
```

All missing data and duplicates look like this.

From the above example, it is clear that some messages has taken the `message_id` of another message, and has been sent twice with two different `message_id`s.

I wonder if anyone would help me figure out what is going on? Thanks in advance.

**Code**

I have an API sending message to pubsub, which looks like this:

```python
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import simplejson as json
from google.cloud import pubsub
from functools import wraps
import re
import json


app = Flask(__name__)
ps = pubsub.Client()

...

@app.route('/publish', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
@json_validator
def publish_test_topic():
    pubsub_topic = 'test_topic'
    data = request.data

    topic = ps.topic(pubsub_topic)

    event = json.loads(data)

    messageId = topic.publish(data)
    return '200 **** sessionId: ' + str(event["sessionId"]) + ", messageId:" + messageId + " ******"
```

And this is the code I used to read from pubsub:

from google.cloud import pubsub
    import re
    import json

```
ps = pubsub.Client()
topic = ps.topic('test-xiu')
sub = topic.subscription('TEST-xiu')

max_messages = 1
stop = False

messages = []

class Message(object):
    """docstring for Message."""
    def __init__(self, sessionId, messageId):
        super(Message, self).__init__()
        self.seesionId = sessionId
        self.messageId = messageId


def pull_all():
    while stop == False:

        m = sub.pull(max_messages = max_messages, return_immediately = False)

        for data in m:
            ack_id = data[0]
            message = data[1]
            messageId = message.message_id
            data = message.data
            event = json.loads(data)
            sessionId = str(event["sessionId"])
            messages.append(Message(sessionId = sessionId, messageId = messageId))

            print '200 **** sessionId: ' + sessionId + ", messageId:" + messageId + " ******"

            sub.acknowledge(ack_ids = [ack_id])

pull_all()
```

For generating session_id, sending request & logging response from API:

```js
// generate trackable sessionId
var sessionId = 0

var increment_session_id = function () {
  sessionId++;
  return sessionId;
}

var generate_data = function () {
  var data = {};
  // data.sessionId = faker.random.uuid();
  data.sessionId = increment_session_id();
  data.user = get_rand(userList);
  data.device = get_rand(deviceList);
  data.visitTime = new Date;
  data.location = get_rand(locationList);
  data.content = get_rand(contentList);

  return data;
}

var sendData = function (url, payload) {
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
      console.log(xhr, status, errorThrown);
      $('.result').prepend("<pre id='json'>" + JSON.stringify(xhr, null, 2) + "</pre>")
      $('.result').prepend("<div>errorThrown: " + errorThrown + "</div>")
      $('.result').prepend("<div>======FAIL=======</div><div>status: " + status + "</div>")
    }
  }).done(function (xhr) {
    console.log(xhr);
    $('.result').prepend("<div>======SUCCESS=======</div><pre id='json'>" + JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2) + "</pre>")
  })
}

$(submit_button).click(function () {
  var request_num = get_request_num();
  var request_url = get_url();
  for (var i = 0; i < request_num; i++) {
    var data = generate_data();
    var loadData = changeVerb(data, 'load');
    sendData(request_url, loadData);
  }
})
```

**UPDATE**

I made a change on the API, and the issue seems to go away. The changes I made was instead of using one `pubsub.Client()` for all request, I initialized a client for every single request coming in. The new API looks like:

```python
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import simplejson as json
from google.cloud import pubsub
from functools import wraps
import re
import json


app = Flask(__name__)

...

@app.route('/publish', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
@json_validator
def publish_test_topic():

    ps = pubsub.Client()


    pubsub_topic = 'test_topic'
    data = request.data

    topic = ps.topic(pubsub_topic)

    event = json.loads(data)

    messageId = topic.publish(data)
    return '200 **** sessionId: ' + str(event["sessionId"]) + ", messageId:" + messageId + " ******"
```

Comment: According to your code, you are publishing every message twice. Is that just a typo or are you indeed publishing each message multiple times?

Comment: Good catch, it's a typo. each request was only sent once. It is now fixed

Comment: Is this another typo? self.seesionId = sessionId. Should it be self.sessionId?

Comment: It is a typo in the code. Thanks for pointing out. Although it wouldn't affect anything, because I'm not using the array of `Message`s anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talked with some guy from Google, and it seems to be an issue with the Python Client:

> The consensus on our side is that there is a thread-safety problem in the current python client.   The client library is being rewritten almost from scratch as we speak, so I don't want to pursue any fixes in the current version.  We expect the new version to become available by end of June.
>
> Running the current code with thread_safe: false in app.yaml or better yet just instantiating the client in every call should is the work around -- the solution you found.

For detailed solution, please see the **Update** in the question

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Pub/Sub message IDs are unique. It should not be possible for "some messages [to] taken the `message_id` of another message." The fact that message ID 108562396466545 was seemingly received means that Pub/Sub did deliver the message to the subscriber and was not lost.

I recommend you check how your `session_id`s are generated to ensure that they are indeed unique and that there is exactly one per message. Searching for the sessionId in your JSON via a regular expression search seems a little strange. You would be better off parsing this JSON into an actual object and accessing fields that way.

In general, duplicate messages in Cloud Pub/Sub are always possible; the system guarantees at-least-once delivery. Those messages can be delivered with the same message ID if the duplication happens on the subscribe side (e.g., the ack is not processed in time) or with a different message ID (e.g., if the publish of the message is retried after an error like a deadline exceeded).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The `session_id` is uniquely generated for each message with incrementing number generator, and I checked the log from App Engine and confirmed every `session_id` sent was unique. I ran the experiment with JSON parser as well, and I'm still observing same behaviour. I'm aware of the duplicate message in pubsub and I'm not worried about them at all. It is the missing messages and the fact that duplicates are taking the `message_id`s of missing messages that worries me.

Comment: Assuming the typo of self.seesionId = sessionId isn't responsible, I recommend you look into the scope of your variables. Are messageId and sessionId global variables on either your publish side or subscribe side? If so, they could be overwritten by concurrent calls to pull_all or publish_test_topic. It seems messages is a global variable so any concurrent calls of pull_all could result in a race condition.

Comment: neither messageId nor sessionId is global on either side. The `messages` is global but not used anywhere. The subscribe side is not on multithread, so there shouldn't be any race condition over there. The only possible race condition that I can see is on the API side, since App Engine could potentially have more than one instance to handle the traffic, so several publish request might be sending to pubsub at same time.

Comment: But since `messageId = topic.publish(data)` returns a `message_id` unique to the message, I'm not sure if there would be an issue

Comment: I made a change on the API, and the issue seems to go away. The changes I made was instead of using one pubsub.Client() for all request, I initialized a client for every single request coming in. I'm not sure why this happens. Do I have to create a new client in every end point?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to create a new client for every publish operation. I'm betting that the reason that that "fixed the problem" is because it mitigated a race that exists in the publisher client side. I'm also not convinced that the log line you've shown on the publisher side:

API: 200 **** sessionId: 731, messageId:108562396466545 ******

corresponds to a successful publish of sessionId 731 by publish_test_topic(). Under what conditions is that log line printed? The code that has been presented so far does not show this.

Comment: The `publish_test_topic()` method returns `return '200 **** sessionId: ' + str(event["sessionId"]) + ", messageId:" + messageId + " ******"`, which is returned to the front-end of the application as the response of each each request to `/publish`, and the it is printed out in the console as soon as it is received